# Using a font from a ttf file in windows / direct3d

Tags: windows, fonts, directx, direct3d

I'm using direct3d 9 and using D3DXCreateFont to create a font object that I can use to write text to the screen. However I want to use a font I have in TTF file instead of an installed font. Is there any way to create a font object from a TTF file without first installing the font into windows which I don't want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [AddFontResourceEx Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183327(VS.85).aspx).

re: MSDN [Font Installation and Deletion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144833(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Ah that was easy once you know what to look for, thank you for the reply.